# How do I install Opera for Linux in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, architecture

I have downloaded Opera for Linux 64-bit version, but when I try to install via Ubuntu Software Center it tells me it is the wrong architecture. What can I do?

Comment: Are you trying to install it on a 64bit Ubuntu install - click top-right cog -> About this computer and see OS Type?

Comment: What I have to do when installing opera is use the "show other versions" link on the download page and select the correct version from there (I select i386) This is because it automatically selects the x86_64x versions, and it doesn't work for my system.

Comment: Official instructions for Debian-based distributions: http://deb.opera.com/manual.html

Answer (score 13):

I'd recommend installing Opera using the Opera repository.  That way it will install the version that is needed and run the updates automatically.

To add the Opera repository, run the following in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free"
wget -O - https://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install opera-stable
```

(if you prefer beta releases, use `deb https://deb.opera.com/opera-beta/ stable non-free` in the first line above).

For more details see the [guide on manual setup of the Opera apt repository](http://deb.opera.com/manual.html).

Comment: Would it make sense to use https instead of http when getting the key? `wget -O - https://...` Just a bit of paranoia.

Answer (score 0):

To install Opera, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

For 32bit

```
wget snapshot.opera.com/unix/dancingelephant_12.13-1725/opera_12.13.1725_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i opera*.deb
```

For 64bit

```
wget snapshot.opera.com/unix/dancingelephant_12.13-1725/opera_12.13.1725_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i opera*.deb
```

<sup>Source:LinuxG</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic Opera repository available at http://deb.opera.com (with full description of how to add it). The Canonical repository for Opera no longer works

```
deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free
```

The line above will make sure you get all final public releases. By default the sources repository is also added (which does not exist for Opera) so remove that. Add the following line if you want to get the newer alpha and beta releases instead.

```
deb http://deb.opera.com/opera-beta/ stable non-free
```

It is advisable that you add the Opera GPG key.

```
wget -qO - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

(If you get "The following packages cannot be authenticated" warnings, you'll also need this:)

```
sudo apt-get install debian-archive-keyring
```

**Install via the shell**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install opera
```